# Combining specific columns into a single column

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
samp_data=data.frame(a=1:5,b=c('22','23','34','21','43'),c=c('11','12','13','54','43')) 

samp_data
 a  b  c
 1 22 11
 2 23 12
 3 34 13
 4 21 54
 5 43 43

str(samp_data)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "21","22","23",..: 2 3 4 1 5
 $ c: Factor w/ 5 levels "11","12","13",..: 1 2 3 5 4
```

I want to convert the above data frame into something like this

```
1 22
1 11
2 23
2 12
3 34
3 13
```

That is keep column 'a' as it is, while combine the other two columns into column 'a'.

I saw some related threads and found these two functions, but I am not getting desired result.

```
dat <- data.frame(samp_data[1], stack(samp_data[2:ncol(samp_data)]))
dat <- melt(samp_data, id.vars=1)
```

Comment: `data.frame(samp_data[1], stack(samp_data[2:ncol(samp_data)]))` will work fine if `a` and `b` are character or numeric and not factors. `stack` skips factors as combining two categorical variables is potentially a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a transpose and concatenate for the subset of columns (without the first) and create a `data.frame` with the first column replicated

```
d1 <- data.frame(a = rep(samp_data[,1], each = 2), b = c(t(samp_data[-1])))
d1
#   a  b
#1  1 22
#2  1 11
#3  2 23
#4  2 12
#5  3 34
#6  3 13
#7  4 21
#8  4 54
#9  5 43
#10 5 43
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned

```
data.frame(samp_data["a"], b=unlist(samp_data[c("b","c")], use.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, actually i posted the wrong output, as to what I want.. I have updated the post. Could you please respond to that

Comment: @bakas Updated the answer

Comment: If ordering is not an issue then just  `data.frame(samp_data["a"], b=unlist(samp_data[c("b","c")]))`